# What is the IUPAC preferred name of this tetracyclic natural product?

Tags: nomenclature, heterocyclic-compounds

On page 819 of Vollhardt, *Organic Chemistry* 7th Ed., the following "subunit of the antibacterial platensimycin" appears. I have attempted to apply von Baeyer and skeletal replacement ('a') nomenclature but am stuck deciding between numberings. Here are some vector drawings: [image: 1]

Is von Baeyer the preferred nomenclature for this molecule? and, if so, what is its correct numbering and preferred IUPAC name?

Comment: [Pubchem](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/platensimycin) has the first bridgehead as the spiro carbon, giving a lower index to one of the secondary bridges: 4-oxo-8-oxatetracyclo[7.2.1.1$^{7,10}$.0$^{1,6}$]tridec-2-ene. I don't have access to the 2013 blue book, so I will refrain from writing an answer. (P-23.2.6.2.4  The superscript locants for the secondary bridges must be as low as possible when considered  as  a  set  in  ascending  numerical  order,  the  decision  being  made  at  the  first  point  of  difference.)

Comment: Instead of a von Baeyer name, Chemoffice as well as the usually good ACD/ChemSketch (2017.2.1) **prefer a fusion name** in this case, i.e. a structure based on 4a,7-methanobenzo[7]annulene. However, I still cannot prove why – when looking into the original IUPAC rules. The resulting name would be 4a,5,6,7,8,9-hexahydro-5,8-epoxy-7,9a-methanobenzo[7]annulen-3(4H)-one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [pubchem](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/platensimycin#section=Names-and-Identifiers) website has given *Platensimycin* IUPAC name, $3$-$[3$-$[(1S,5S,6R,7S,9S,10S)$-$5,9$-dimethyl-$4$-oxo-$8$-oxatetracyclo$[7.2.1.1^{7,10}.0^{1,6}]$tridec-$2$-en-$5$-yl]propanoylamino]-$2,4$-dihydroxybenzoic acid (see attached picture):

[image: Platensimycin]

Accordingly, since https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov is usually updating data according to the changes, I believe the name of the cyclic system (without 5,9-dimethyl groups) OP is asking is same as one in the comment by @KarstenTheis (including the correct stereochemistry): $(1S,5S,6R,7S,9S,10S)$-$4$-oxo-$8$-oxatetracyclo$[7.2.1.1^{7,10}.0^{1,6}]$tridec-$2$-ene (see the blue numbering in the picture).

**Late correction:** After exchanging few comments with Loong, I realized that the given system should be treated as a chemical compound. Accordingly, the name should have been: $(1S,5S,6R,7S,9S,10S)$-$4$-oxo-$8$-oxatetracyclo$[7.2.1.1^{7,10}.0^{1,6}]$tridec-$2$-en-$4$-one (as suggested by Loong).

Comment: "since https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov is usually updating data according to the changes" – do we know that they are really doing this?

Comment: I have seen changing of data on physical properties section. But not sure for everything, though.

Comment: How do we know that the correct name for the moiety *as a substituent* is the same as its correct name as its own molecule?

Comment: Not exactly the same but related. See, the priority changes going from substituent to a molecule. For example, 4-oxo- for substituent becomes 4-one on the molecule.

Comment: In the full IUPAC name for Platensimycin, why is it "-4-yl]propylamino" instead of "-5-yl]propylamino"? Isn't the tetracyclic part connected to the propylamino part at carbon 5?

Answer (score 2):

An elder version of Chemdoodle (8.1.0) suggests a name slightly different from the one in the comment by @KarstenTheis, 8-Oxotetracyclo$[7.2.1.1^{7,10}.0^{1,6}]$-tridec-2-3n-4-one.

It may be that I erred while drawing the molecule into the sketcher, hence for a xcheck the screen photo below. The yellowish' spheres indicate Chemdoodle's selection for the current naming -- there are only two atoms of oxygen.

[image]